# MySQL Database Randomly Stops Taking in Data?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I'm working on a nice little application. I'm making a Tick counter, to count how many times the program runs. However, randomly it stops entering data at like 1355... I have to get it to keep running until it hits 5000. But sometimes it goes over to like 5002... Lost on that one too... I would prefer the loop to run forever until it's terminated. If anyone can help me on that you get a bit cookie. In conclusion, my main problem is putting data in the database continuously, with out random stops.

```
while($run && $dataA['StateOfBot'] == 1){
    if($dataA['Tick'] >= 5000){
        mysql_query("UPDATE state SET StateOfBot = 0 WHERE ID = 1;");
    }
    $dataA['Tick'] = $dataA['Tick'] + 1;
    mysql_query("UPDATE state SET Tick = '".$dataA['Tick']."' WHERE ID = 1;");
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM state");
    $dataA = mysql_fetch_array($data);
}
```

Comment: The more than 5000 problem smells like a sync problem. If more than one thread is entering tnis section of code that behavior could occur. Why don't make this code a critical section?

Comment: What is critical section? Do you have a website with an example?

Comment: Forget it, it looks like PHP scripts are single thread so my supposition can't be the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is quite buggy

```
while($run && $dataA['StateOfBot'] == 1){
    if($dataA['Tick'] >= 5000){
        mysql_query("UPDATE state SET StateOfBot = 0 WHERE ID = 1;");
        break; //get out of the loop
    }
    $dataA['Tick'] = $dataA['Tick'] + 1;
    mysql_query("UPDATE state SET Tick = '".$dataA['Tick']."' WHERE ID = 1;");
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT onefield_only FROM state");
    $dataA = mysql_fetch_array($data);
}
```

I tried to fix it a little. You need a break statement to get out of the loop.